# How does sklearn KNeighborsClassifier score method work?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

```
knn.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Here `X_test` is a numpy array that contains test cases and `y_test` contains their correct labels.

This is the code that returns the reliability score of a model I made to differentiate between species of iris.

How does this function work, does it predict every value from X_test array and then compares it with y_test array and computes the mean?

Comment: Are you looking at the sklearn's KNeighborsClassifier?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KNeighborsClassifier` is a subclass of the [`sklearn.base.ClassifierMixin`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.ClassifierMixin.html). From the documentation of the `score` method:

> Returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.
>
> In multi-label classification, this is the subset accuracy which is a harsh metric since you require for each sample that each label set be correctly predicted.

The source code itself for the `score` method:

```
return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

It's simply a shortcut for producing predictions on the test data and computing the [accuracy score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html#sklearn-metrics-accuracy-score) against the given labels.